# Clearing two cells when I leave/re-enter the tab tab

Tags: vba, excel

I tried browsing online but no luck.

I would like to clear cell A1 and A2 (dropdown but this shouldn't matter) in Sheet1 upon leaving Sheet1 and moving to any other Sheet within the workbook. How can I do it?

Thanks

Ewa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the following event in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Worksheets("TheSpecialOne").Range("A1:A2").Clear
End Sub
```

It will clear the `A1:A2`, for the sheet named "TheSpecialOne". Write the code here:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vityata, this is great and indeed this is what I asked for, however, is it easy to modify so that that Clearhappens on the re-enter to Sheet1? Currently upon the selection in dropdowns in Sheet1 a Sheet2 is filtered based on A1 and A2 selections, so if I clear dropdowns immediately after leaving Sheet 1, the filter doesn't work. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ewuchatka - put a condition like `If Sh.Name <> "TheSpecialOne" then exit sub`.